# frozen filter in Acumatica 21R1

Tags: c#, acumatica

hi i am having this problem with a filter.

The filter works only the first time, later when I change it the first value found is frozen.

I share captures and BQL

[first filter OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVcbr.png)

[filter changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unAGz.png)

```
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoinGroupBy<APPayment,
        USRAPPaymentFilterTXT,
        InnerJoin<APAdjust,
            On<APPayment.docType,
                Equal<APAdjust.adjgDocType>,
                    And<APPayment.refNbr,
                        Equal<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr>>>,
            InnerJoin<APRegister,
                On<APPayment.refNbr,
                    Equal<APRegister.refNbr>,
                        And<APPayment.docType,
                            Equal<APRegister.docType>>>,
            InnerJoin<APInvoice,
                On<APAdjust.adjdDocType,
                    Equal<APInvoice.docType>,
                    And<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr,
                        Equal<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>>>,
            Where<APInvoice.paySel, Equal<True>,
                And<APPayment.cashAccountID, Equal<USRAPPaymentFilterTXT.cashAccountID.FromCurrent>
                    , And<APPayment.docDate, Between<USRAPPaymentFilterTXT.from.FromCurrent, USRAPPaymentFilterTXT.to.FromCurrent>
                        , And<APRegister.status, Equal<APRegisterStatusBalanced>>
                        >
                    >>,
            Aggregate<GroupBy<APPayment.docType,
                GroupBy<APPayment.refNbr, 
                Max<APPayment.curyOrigDocAmt>>>>>
        txtgenerate;
```

Comment: In your first screenshot, notice that the description of the account is filled in.  In the 2nd screenshot, it is not.  If you tab out of the field, does it fill in the description or update the grid?

Comment: In recent Acumatica versions, in 'Apply Updates' page there is a 'Clear Cache' button. Try to see if this resets the 'works only once'. Otherwise I would think we miss details to understand the issue.

Comment: when i click outside the filter it does auto fill again i also cleared the cache

Comment: How are you changing the filter value? Do you open Selector popup and select one of the valid values from the grid?

Comment: I open the selector and select one of the values, then the filter is updated and the results change, this works fine the first time but as soon as I interact with any of the values ​​or I want to do the filtering again, the first line is frozen and update me the rest

Answer (score 0):

Is your Cash Account lookup set to CommitChanges=true?